# Categorize data with Vlookup in Google Sheets without the help of a helper table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to categorize data in Google Sheets by using array function, without the help of helper tables. I cannot figured out how to put incremented values in an array function. For example, if I have a table like:

| Name |
| --- |
| cup |
| cup |
| pencil |
| pencil |
| book |
| table |

I can use a helper table to name each group and use a Vlookup formula to get the below table with the formula,

```
vlookup($A1,$D$2:$E$4,2,0)
```

, where `$D$2:$E$4` is the reference table.

| Name | Group |
| --- | --- |
| cup | groupid1 |
| cup | groupid1 |
| pencil | groupid2 |
| pencil | groupid2 |
| book | groupid3 |
| table | groupid4 |

Instead of the reference table I was wondering if I could use a array function or array in the `VLOOKUP` formula.

For example something like,

```
{unique(A1:A),if(/referance-to-index-1 of unique(A1:A) != 0/,"GROUPID[1 auto-incremented]","" )}
```

So that I get an array like this, please ignore the heading,

| Name | Group |
| --- | --- |
| cup | groupid1 |
| pencil | groupid2 |
| book | groupid3 |
| table | groupid4 |

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear (at least not to me). Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet, being clear about what/where the original source data is and what/where the results should be. Manually enter those results as you would like to see a formula produce them. This will be the most efficient and effective means of receiving help from the volunteer contributors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment to your original post.

That being said, here is my guess as to what you mean.

Suppose that your original list is in Sheet1!A2:A. Try this formula in A1 of some other empty sheet:

`=ArrayFormula({UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")),"GROUPID"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)))})`

Comment: Thnak you very much @Erik this is exactly what I was looking for. The lookup function worked with this Arrayformula .

Comment: Ah. If you were starting with {cup;cup;pencil;pencil...} in A2:A of some sheet and wanted to produce the results in Col B, just delete everything from Col B and place this in B1: `=ArrayFormula({"ID";IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,{UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),"GROUPID"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A)))},2,FALSE))})`